# related news and articles block on content page based on tags

Tags: views

I have to create a block that contain five article based on the tags which is get displayed on the content page.Below is the view i created.

[image]

The output of this view is

[image]

here in the sidebar the article having the same tag in the content page is shown,but the content is getting repeated twice.can anyone tell me why the content in the block is getting repeated

Answer (score 0):

most probably you have more tags on the related content, so it is shown several times. try selecting "distinct values" in Query settings

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "Content: has term ...." in Filter Criteria

[image]

By the way, if you are interested in other modules to do this sort of task, you can check out, http://drupal.org/project/featured_content

can

- List of content that has one of the same terms as the node being shown